# Flag disappears after reading a message in Mail

Tags: mail.app, macos

In Mail 9.0 (OS X El Capitan) I have set a rule that marks a message with a flag if it satisfies some conditions. 
When I receive a message which satisfies that condition, it is correctly marked with the flag, but when I read the message, the flag disappears and the message is automatically unmarked.
How can this be explained? I would like to always keep the flag, also after reading the message.

Comment: I experience a similar behaviour with the Junk flag. Junk emails are initially correctly marked as junk, but shortly after the flag disappears.

Answer (score -1):

I reported this as a bug in 2006. It appears that Apple either doesn't use Mail or doesn't care about this feature.

You can get add-on software, such as Mailhub, to repair this feature.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).  Flagging for removal as not an answer. - From Review